# How can I use decltype to access a dependent-type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

First: my apologies if I am getting the nomenclature wrong!

Basically, I have a not-too-uncommon desire to declare a stack based container, such as:

```
std::map<CString, size_t> ecounts;
```

Then I want to iterate over the contents of ecounts a little further down in the function body, but I really don't want to have to typedef a bunch of things, nor retype the above types in order to get the compiler to work with what I have...

```
std::foreach(ecounts.begin(), ecounts.end(), [&] (>>>here is the problem<<< e)
{
  ... whatever I want to do with e ...
}
```

Of course, I can either use typedefs, or my knowledge of the declaration of ecounts manually:

```
std::foreach(ecounts.begin(), ecounts.end(), [&] (std::pair<CString,size_t> e)
...
```

But, yuck!  I'd much rather have a single declaration of what ecounts is, and just use it's value_type somehow.  But this seems not to work:

```
std::foreach(ecounts.begin(), ecounts.end(), [&] (decltype(ecounts)::value_type e)
...
```

Is this just a limitation of my compiler (vs2010), or is this a limitation of C++?

How might I go about making a sort of One Definition Rule to such code, preferably without having to use typedefs to achieve it (i.e., I can do the following):

```
typedef std::map<CString, size_t> maptype;
typedef maptype::value_type valuetype;
maptype ecounts;
...
std::foreach(ecounts.begin(), ecounts.end(), [&] (valuetype e)
...
```

This is not the end of the world, obviously, but if I can use decltype, I'd be happier with the resulting reduction in thinking & backtracking to achieve the above...

Comment: MS implementation of `decltype` is quite buggy. Unfortunately, standardization committee didn't adopt polymorphic lambdas, this would be nicer `std::for_each(ecounts.begin(), ecounts.end(), [&] (auto e) {});` It's also strange the standard library never added an overload for the most frequently used case: `for_each(C&& container, F&& function);` which would be equivalent to `for_each(begin(container), end(container), function);` If that has been done there wouldn't be any need for range based `for`.

Comment: I've always found the STL (and now std) to suck in that regard.  Why not at least provide templates that take the actual container, and apply std::begin(container), std::end(container)?  Most of my own libraries supply this variation, since it's what I want 99% of the time.  Specifying some other bounding conditions is, in my coding, quite rare.

Comment: The reason standard algorithms can't take containers directly is because they wouldn't be able to distinguish a version that takes a container and a predicate or other optional param from one that take two iterators an no extra param. Concepts would have fixed this.

Comment: @bames53 This?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29

Comment: @bames53 -- that could be fixed without concepts, using `std::enable_if` template and creating `is_container` trait using SFINAE. I've done a lot of similar things, even VC2010 can handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Limitation of VS2010, as the addition you want came into the standard too late for it. It should compile with a conformant compiler. As a workaroung, just use `decltype(*ecounts.begin()) e`. Or an identity template:

```
template<class T>
struct identity{ typedef T type; };
// usage: identity<decltype(ecounts)>::type::value_type
```

Comment: VC++ 2010 ships with the identity template, `std::identity<>` -- no need to recreate it. :-]

Comment: @Ildjarn: Sure, but it's out of the standard, since template typedefs in C++11 are better. Forward compatability ftw? :)

Comment: Possibly, but knowing MS, they'll never remove `identity<>` from namespace `std` for backwards compatibility reasons now that they've shipped it. :-P

Comment: @ildjiarn: True enough, but what about portability? Ha! (I'll find an argument to keep that recreated `identity` for sure.)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is a normal iteration over the container, just use a new style for loop:

```
for (auto e: ecounts)
{
   // whatever you want to do with e
}
```

Or if you want to modify the elements in the map:

```
for (auto& e: ecounts)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Alas, not yet supported by Visual Studio.

Comment: really nice option.  I'm looking forward to the next version of VS. :)